# 'string' does not contain a definition for helper when looping through ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a unique 'string' does not contain definition problem.

Take following VIew code:

```
@if (ViewBag.Stories != null)
{
    if (ViewBag.Stories.Count > 0)
    {
    <h2>Stories (@ViewBag.Stories.Count)</h2>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Stories)
        {
            <li>
                @("test".ToString().ToSeoUrl())
                <h2>@(item.Title.ToString().ToSeoUrl())</h2>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    }
}
```

If I remove '.ToString().ToSeoUrl()' from item.Title I get:

- test

  title
- test

  title
- test

  title

If I add it back. I get the excepction

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToSeoUrl'

I'm using Razor and have the following helper class registered in the View:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyNamespace.Helpers
{    
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static string ToSeoUrl(this string url)
        {
        // make the url lowercase
        string encodedUrl = (url ?? "").ToLower();

        // replace & with and
        encodedUrl = Regex.Replace(encodedUrl, @"\&+", "and");

        // remove characters
        encodedUrl = encodedUrl.Replace("'", "");

        // remove invalid characters
        encodedUrl = Regex.Replace(encodedUrl, @"[^a-z0-9]", "-");

        // remove duplicates
        encodedUrl = Regex.Replace(encodedUrl, @"-+", "-");

        // trim leading & trailing characters
        encodedUrl = encodedUrl.Trim('-');

        return encodedUrl;
        }
    }
}
```

item is a custom class called Story with a public string Title

Comment: How is the helper class 'registered' in the view?

Comment: I've also tried moving the namespace registering out to the web.config and placing the call within a @{} with no luck.

Comment: @using MyNamespace.Helpers;

and in web.config (both top and view level)
        <add namespace="MyNamespace.Helpers"/>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Because you are using `ViewBag` which is `dynamic` and `ToSeoUrl` which is an extension method you get an `RuntimeBinderException`.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Use casting: `<h2>@(((string)item.Title).ToSeoUrl())</h2>` calling `ToString()` is not enough because it will be also dynamically dispatched.
2. Call your extension method without the extension method syntax as a normal static method: `<h2>@(StringExtensions.ToSeoUrl(item.Title))</h2>`

Comment: Thank You! Knew there had to be something I was missing.